# How to use map function inside an array of nested object and assigining the result to the same object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, geocoding

I have array of objects with below sample data:

```
const data = [
{
  videoId: 'vfLdGddGwOw',
  title: 'Central Vietnamese Street Food!! Noodles from Actual Heaven!!',
  thumbnail: {
    url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vfLdGddGwOw/maxresdefault.jpg',
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
  },
  address: [
    '49/3 Trần Hưng Đạo, Sơn Phong, Hội An, Quảng Nam 56000',
    'Lê Thánh Tông street, An Phú ward, Tam Kỳ city, Quảng Nam Province'
  ],
},
{
  videoId: 'bol-_4NZjWE',
  title: 'Risky Thai Street Food!! Even Locals Don’t Eat This!!',
  thumbnail: {
    url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bol-_4NZjWE/sddefault.jpg',
    width: 640,
    height: 480
  },
  address: [
    '87 Baan Patan, T. San Pakwan, A. Hang Dong, Chiang Mai',
    'Hang Dong, Chiang Mai 50230',
    '221 Soi Hang San, Ban Waen, Hang Dong District, Chiang Mai 50230',
  ],
}
```

I'd like to geocode all the addresses in each object and assign the result to the object like this :

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    address: [
      {
        location: "49/3 Trần Hưng Đạo, Sơn Phong, Hội An, Quảng Nam 56000",
        coordinate: [15.87944, 108.335],
      },
      {
        location:
          "Lê Thánh Tông street, An Phú ward, Tam Kỳ city, Quảng Nam Province",
        coordinate: [20.95533, 107.06892],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    address: [
      {
        location: "87 Baan Patan, T. San Pakwan, A. Hang Dong, Chiang Mai",
        coordinate: [18.76794, 98.996512],
      },
      {
        location: "Hang Dong, Chiang Mai 50230",
        coordinate: [49.038833, -1.581446],
      },
      {
        location:
          "221 Soi Hang San, Ban Waen, Hang Dong District, Chiang Mai 50230",
        coordinate: [18.76794, 98.996512],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

How can I do that? This what I currently have:

```
const geocode = async (element) => {
  const baseURL = `http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward`;

  const params = {
    access_key: "API_KEY",
    query: element,
    limit: 1,
    output: "geojson",
    country_module: 0,
    sun_module: 0,
    timezone_module: 0,
    bbox_module: 0,
  };

  try {
    const fetchGeocode = axios.get(baseURL, { params });
    const geocodedData = fetchGeocode.data;
    element.push(geocodedData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

data.map((obj) => {
obj.address.map((element) => geocode(element))
}
)
```

When I use it, I get error: TypeError: element.push is not a function.

How can I geocode the coordinate of each address in the array of object and then push/ assign the coordinate in the same?

Comment: Expected result is invalid

Comment: Apologies, I added my code. Any idea where I got it wrong?

Comment: Please provide the correct `data`, `address(1)`, `latitude(2)` and so on. You now have invalid `data`.

Comment: I've added the first 2 object in the array of objects as sample data. Help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: I just wrapped the expected result in the `live demo` widget. Now if you press `Run code snippet` - an error drops out due to syntax. Could you please provide the correct expected data that doesn't crash with errors?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've added the expected result and checked the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```js
const geocode = async (address) => {
  const baseURL = `http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward`;

  const params = {
    access_key: "API_KEY",
    query: address,
    limit: 1,
    output: "geojson",
    country_module: 0,
    sun_module: 0,
    timezone_module: 0,
    bbox_module: 0,
  };

  try {
    const fetchGeocode = axios.get(baseURL, { params });
    const geocodedData = fetchGeocode.data;
    return geocodedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// will map each item of the data array and search  each address at the api
// then, will return an array of {'the_adrress_string': theResultOfTheApi}
// i've use this return because of the example that you show the result that you want to have
const mapGeocode = async (data) => {
   const addressesMaped = Promise.all(
     data.address.map(async(address)=> {
      const geocodeData = await geocode(address)

      // i don't know the return of this api, but this will return something like: 
    // {'87 Baan Patan, T. San Pakwan, A. Hang Dong, Chiang Mai': coordinate:{latitude, longitude}}

    // if you prefer, you could return {address: address, cordinate: ...geocodeData}
      return {
       [address]: geocodeData
      }
     }) 

   )
   return data
})

// this should be inside a async function 
data = await Promise.all(
   data.map(mapGeocode)
)
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it! Since my understanding of Promise.all is lacking, could you tell me what is the purpose of Promise.all here?

Comment: It was used there to resolve all asynchronous operations done inside the .map